# Pros and cons of static social (share button) links?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, twitter, pinterest

After playing around with social media buttons I've realized that it takes some time to load them when following the standard javascript approach. e.g for facebook it is something like :

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
...
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=180631328718700";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Loading time even increases when multiple buttons (fb,g+,twitter,pinterest....) are present. This can be avoided by using static links like :

http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fplugins%2F&width&layout=standard&action=like&show_faces=true&share=true&height=80

Which in facebook case is in the documentation, but for example pinterest mention only javascript approach in their documentation. However also for pinterest case it is easy to find out what the link should look like.

I can see some advantages of the javascript : one can see the click counts, nice popups for free. This is for the cost of longer load time (which can be even longer on mobile devices). Another disadvantage of javascript is that it could be quite hard to handle dynamic websites.

The advantage of static links is definitely loading speed and simple development of dynamic pages for the cost of living without click counts and nice popups. There are also no DOM changes done by social javascripts (which are in general doing heavy dom changes)

Is there anything else? What about the backward compatibility of the links - could the link template change in the future?

Answer (score 2):

I like how you aim to reduce the overhead of these widgets. I'm on the same boat.

If a social button is not documented, you can see the result of the JavaScript transformation, and use the static link equivalence. The catch is, of course, that they will change their template at some point without knowing that you're still quoting the old way. That is definitely a drawback.

Another benefit, in addition to less DOM manipulation, is fewer connections. Some JavaScript injects an iFrame, which significantly delays the page load.

You can do a lazy loader, and still have JavaScript interaction. Just don't use the copy-and-paste ready code that's convenient but inefficient.